# React RTK hook cleaner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtk-query

I am storing the current user in a API call and use it in the components like this:

```
const { data: meCurrentUser } = useMeCurrentUserQuery({})
const currentUser = meCurrentUser!.data!
```

How can I make this cleaner? I do not like to use these 2 lines just to get the current user state...

Comment: Do you mean something like `const { data: { data: currentUser } = {} } = useMeCurrentUserQuery({})`? I hope you are sure what you are doing with those non-null assertions there

Comment: Yes. I’m sure the user is logged in when this code is used.

Comment: Still it's usually a good practice to at least `if(!currenttUser) return null` so that there is no way to get a runtime error in case something ever goes wrong or the architecture of the app changes. But it's up to you in the end

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion on how to handle this?

Comment: If you are sure the user must be present, you could do `if (!currentUser) throw new Error("Expected user to be logged in")`, so if something goes wrong you will get an error. You could also move this logic to a custom hook like `useLoggedUser` that would get user with `useMeCurrentUserQuery` and throw an error if it is null. These are the simplest and most common ways I can think of

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "cleaner" one-line code, then check this:

```js
// if you're sure the user never gets undefined,   replace `?.` by `!.`
const currentUser = useMeCurrentUserQuery({})?.data?.data
```